# Dynamics CRM - Invoke Action in Workflow

Tags: workflow, action, dynamics-crm

The page [Invoke custom action from a workflow or dialog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn949331.aspx) on Microsoft's site shows it's possible to call an Action as a step in a Workflow, but I cannot figure out how. It's not on the Add Step dropdown no matter what I try. Yet they have this image showing that an "Action" step is possible. How?

[image: Workflow action step]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom workflow activity to call the action from the workflow. Here's an example of how you can do

```
OrganizationRequest req = new OrganizationRequest("new_ActionName");
req["ParameterName"] = "string parameter";
req["Target"] = new EntityReference("new_entityofaction", idOfEntity);

//execute the request
OrganizationResponse response = service.Execute(req);
```